# How to run multiple internal javascript codes asynchronously and not block?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a webpage created by a php script that upon loading will contain 0 to N div elements. For each div I run a specific javascript code that manipulates data relevant to that div.
One of the things this code does is create an *img* element and set its '*src*' attribute to a certain url of an image of a known (but variable) size. This is done for caching. Those images are not supposed to be displayed in the initial page layout - but each should appear after a certain user input (mouse hover) - so I'm trying to cache the images so it won't take long for them to appear.

The loading of the images of-course takes time - and each time an image loads the code blocks resulting in high load times. an example:

```
<div id="i1">
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* run code relevant to 'i1', and amongst other things load some image 
      into a detached img element for later use. let's call this code 'bcode' */
</script>
<div id="i2">
<script type="text/javascript">
   /* run 'bcode' for i2 */
</script>

<div id="...and so on">
```

To try having the code run asynchronously, I tried this:

```
<div id="i1">
(function() {
   var asyncScriptElement = document.createElement('script');
   asyncScriptElement.async = true;
   var scriptText = document.createTextNode ('here I put all of the relevant "bcode"');
   asyncScriptElement.appendChild (scriptText);
   document.getElementById ('Img_1_2').appendChild (asyncScriptElement);
 }());
```

It works under FF (still not fast enough), and it obviously doesn't work under IE.
Do you have any suggestion as to how to achieve this?
Also note, that I don't really need to get anything from another external php (i.e. to use XMLHttpRequest) - I got all the data I need in this php. I just need a way to make the loading of the images unblocking...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the waitfor/and construct provided by the apollo library: http://onilabs.com/stratifiedjs#waitfor-and

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap your scripts in an HTML page (eventually generated by PHP) and download it as an iframe to assure the same behaviour for any browser.

There are other more elegant options with pros and cons; [here](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/) you can find a comparison of viable options, browser compatibility and a nice decision tree.

Comment: will I be able to reference js variables of the outer document from inside the js that will be in the iframes?

Comment: Nope. You can include additional parameters in the iframe src and use those parameters via PHP or JS within the iframe.

Comment: @Yuval, @ibz if your iframes are on the same domain (same-origin) you have full access to everything in both window objects.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded and always runs synchronously.

There are browser extensions to get around this, notably the concept of [Javascript Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) in Mozilla

Comment: True, but there are a number of ways to make parallel execution of different Javascript code in the same page. Mozilla Javascript Workers and HTML5 Web Workers are great solutions that we will be hopefully able to adopt in the near future.

Comment: That isn't entirely accurate but I digress.